# Defining Current Density in a FEM model (MATLAB)

Tags: finite-element, computational-physics, numerics

I'm attempting to solve the Poisson equation in 3D for a magnetic vector potential in the presence of a current source. To validate my code, I'm initially looking to reproduce the model described in the following pair of papers:

> - N. Demerdash, T. Nehl and F. Fouad, "Finite element formulation and analysis of three dimensional magnetic field problems," in IEEE Transactions on Magnetics, vol. 16, no. 5, pp. 1092-1094, September 1980.
>     doi: 10.1109/TMAG.1980.1060817
>     URL: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1060817&isnumber=22843
> - N. A. Demerdash, F. A. Fouad, T. W. Nehl and O. A. Mohammed, "Three Dimensional Finite Element Vector Potential Formulation of Magnetic Fields in Electrical Apparatus," in IEEE Transactions on Power Apparatus and Systems, vol. PAS-100, no. 8, pp. 4104-4111, Aug. 1981. doi: 10.1109/TPAS.1981.317005. URL: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4111101&isnumber=4111054

The paper gives the following figure to describe the coil which carries the current: [image]

Alongside the following parameters:

- 20 Amps of current.
- Wire is of type AWG #16 with 861 turns
- Winding Height (Z axis): 8.89cm
- Outer Boundary Cross Section: 15.24 cm x 15.24 cm
- Inner Boundary Cross Section: 10.42 cm x 10.42 cm

I also know that the current density should be homogeneous in a specific element. In this model Jz = 0 throughout and I know **J** = N*I / A, where A is the cross sectional area, N the number of turns and I the current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining current density in this system can be done by considering the average current density within the winding region, $J_{0}$ (then subdividing this into elements). For winding height h, Inner cross section $L_{1}$, Outer cross section $L_{2}$ with N turns carrying current I:

$ J_{0} = \frac{IN}{h(L_{2} - L_{1})/2} $.

I note this expression does not incorporate the specific wire properties which are also specified in the paper - this maybe to allow physical reconstruction of the system rather than for the modelling side.